# How do collective origins work?

Tags: council, origin, pallet-collective

I am trying to learn how to use the `collective` module and started my chain using just 1 council member. Then I create a proposal for some function like set_balance, and execute it with a threshold of 1. Since I am the only member in the council I assumed it would pass.

After a few moments I can see a successful dispatch, but on the explorer I see this :
[image]

What does this mean and where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't tell much without seeing your code, but looks like a few things:

1. `set_balance` requires Root origin, so Council won't be enough, unless you configure your Root origin to be from Council.
2. To dispatch from the Council, you should use `propose`, `vote`, and `close` from the Collective pallet. If approved, then it will [construct the necessary origin](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/32510e13afa84a2fa917a94e5d7e18d480a34a22/frame/collective/src/lib.rs#L869) and dispatch the call.

Comment: Could you tell me what code snip you'd like to see? Would the pallet_collective config suffice?

Comment: At least that plus the configuration of any `Origin` you want to use it for. Probably the whole runtime lib.rs would be useful.